# Azure RM Template. Deploy copy VM with Key Vault password

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to automate deployment of variable amount of VMs (deployed via copy) by replacing password by Key Vault secrets. I would like to use different secrets for different VMs (ex secret1 for VM1, secret2 for VM2). According to documentation I need to reference a secret with dynamic id https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-dynamic-id
I've tweaked documentation example to utilize copy for deployment of my VMs, but I'm struggling to change secretName to secretName1, secretName2 upon each call of the nested template. How can I do that?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "vaultName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "secretName": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "[concat('nestedTemplate-', copyIndex())]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nestedTemplateLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "mode": "incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "https://www.contoso.com/AzureTemplates/newVM.json",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('vaultName'))]"
              },
              "secretName": "[parameters('secretName')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: how do those differ? example?

Comment: I don't even know how to do it on a simple VM. If you happened to see a good example, please share it.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-secure-password/azuredeploy.json

Comment: @4c74356b41, I've went through the template you linked and learned quiet a bit. Although, my question still stands I have updated it to so it's more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"secretName": [concat(parameters('secretName'), copyIndex())]
```

Comment: A code-only answer is indeed an answer, but could probably benefit from some context / explanation.

Comment: there's nothing to explain, this is a very simple expression, its pretty intuitive

Comment: You need to explain how does this expression solves the problem. How is it different from the one that the OP had?

Comment: This answer does solve my problem of changing secretName upon each call of the nested template. But with this approach another problem arises... Because I use copy inside the nested template and to call the nested template it self there may be a conflict. Let's say I would like to deploy 2 VMs with passwords as secret1 and secret2. But my nested template would do it twice! With password "secret1" for VM1 and VM2 and also will attempt to deploy VM1 and VM2 with password as "secret2" for both VMs. How can I overcome that?

Comment: well, don't create 2 vm's in nested template? create only one? @Max

Comment: But that's the whole point! I don't want to create one VM, I would like to specify how many VMs will be deployed via parameters, and for the first VM secret1 would be used, for the second secret2 and so on.

Comment: Well, you should accept this as an answer and create a new question, because this is a completely new question